# Word to describe being happy yet sad

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that means both happy and a bit sad? As when you finish a really good book that you were totally immersed in and had the perfect ending. You are so pleased with the story yet sad that it is over. Could also apply to people and relationships. I know there is a word for this yet I can’t call it forward. (not bittersweet)

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: In addition to a sample sentence, please explain why "bittersweet" doesn't work exactly.

Comment: There is [**suadade**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade) although I've only just discovered [this word](https://www.lexico.com/definition/saudade) and am unfamiliar with its usage.

Answer (score 0):

wistful

(also, note Hamlet, Act I, Scene i:
with a defeated joy,
With an auspicious and a dropping eye,
With mirth in funeral and with dirge in marriage,
In equal scale weighing delight and dole....)

Comment: Do you have a authoritative definition of "wistful" that states the meaning of simultaneously happy and sad?